# how to push and clone repository from self-hosted gitlab instance

Tags: git, gitlab

I run a gitlab-ce using docker

```
docker run --detach   --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 8080:22   --name gitlab   --restart always   --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab   --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab   --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab   --shm-size 256m gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

I created a repository on gitlab using the browser, I can figure out how to push and clone repository from that gitlab instance into my local machine

Comment: *"I can figure out how to push and clone repository"* - I assume you wanted to write "can't". But yes, you can. It works the same way as working with GitHub. Add your public key to your profile. Make sure your user has permissions to clone. It should then work as usual. Is there any error message? Have you searched the error text? It's difficult to give you an answer if you're simply stuck at this step. Have you searched a tutorial the internet? The [official gitlab docker documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html) can certainly help.

Comment: I meant I can't
so I need to add the public key of my local machine on that gitlab instance and give permission to that user to clone.
I have a question I need to specify the port 8080 on the git clone command since I mapped port 8080 on the host to port 22 to the gitlab container

Comment: Follow the documentation I linked for you. Their examples show `--publish 22:22`. First, follow the docs first until it works, then make modifications if you know what you're doing.